# How to change bg recyclerview specific position [ Kotlin ]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**Q1**
I make some recyclerview with cardview I want to click some position and change bg current position to black and another position to green in the adapter

**Q2**
I want to change something specific position in the adapter

```
class RecyclerAdapterBrand(private var imageList: List<Int>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterBrand.ViewHolder>() {

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewBrand)
    val cardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewBrand)

    init {
        // Set Recycler Click
        itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            val positionClick: Int = (adapterPosition + 1)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.recy_brand_layout,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.post {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageList[position])
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return imageList.size
}
```

Comment: Share your code snippets,

Comment: Edited add code already

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of the clicked item easily.You have to create a variable called `selectedposition` and assigned to `-1`. Whenever you click the item you have to set the clicked `position` value to `selectedPosition`.And call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on recyclerview's item ClickListener method. Then in `OnBindViewHolder()` method you have to check if the position & selected position are same, set the background color to green.otherwise set the background color to black.

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var selectedPosition=-1
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewBrand)
    val cardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewBrand)

    init {
        // Set Recycler Click
        itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            selectedPosition=(adapterPosition + 1)
            val positionClick: Int = (adapterPosition + 1)
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.recy_brand_layout,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
   if(selectedPosition==position){

    holder.itemView.setBackground(#green color)
    }else{
    
    holder.itemView.post {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(#black color)
    }

   }



}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return imageList.size
}
```

I have included those lines in your adapter class.I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I changed "selectedPosition" to 2 in setOnClickListener
but on onBindViewHolder "selectedPosition" stay -1

Comment: did you called notifyDataSetChanged() in in setOnClickListener??